# R - filtering negative and positive spikes in data

Tags: r, filter, trim

I am plotting a data that consists of some intervals that are more or less constant, and spikes in the data originating from the data being a quotient from two parameters. The relatively high and large quotients aren't not relevant for my purpose, so I have been looking for a way to filter these out. The dataset contains 40k+ values so I can not manually remove the high/low quotients.

Is there any function that can trim/filter out the very large/small quotients?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Without additional details, perhaps example data, it will be difficut to get good answers to your question. Please see [ask] to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter()` function from `dplyr`. This can create a new dataframe without outliers that you can then plot. For example:

`no_spikes <- filter(original_df, x > -100 & x < 100)`
This would create a new dataframe, `no_spikes`, that only contains observations where the variable x is between the values -100 and 100.